# why Class class need to be Generic?

Tags: java, generics

for example:

```
Class<String> c = String.class;
```

I think, the Class object of the String may have a method to know, that it's act on a String type.

so, the type param is no need.

Comment: `public final native Class<?> getClass()` this is the method defined in Object.class

Comment: *Non sequitur.* Generics provide type safety, not just type information.

Comment: thank you, Sotirios, I make a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking why `Class` is now generic, it's so that type-safe generic methods can accept a `Class` parameter to provide a type bound.

Consider `EnumSet`. The way to create an empty `EnumSet` of `MyEnum` is to use `noneOf`:

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> set = EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class)
```

Since `Class` is generic, the compiler knows that the static `noneOf` method will be returning an `Enum<MyEnum>`. This idiom is used extensively in persistence and remoting APIs, such as JPA type-safe queries and Spring Data projections, where you provide a class literal at compile time, and the compiler understands that the API will be returning an instance of that class.

An example in the standard JRE: The legacy `ResultSet#getObject(int columnIndex)` method returns an `Object` which you must then cast. The new `ResultSet#getObject(int columnIndex, Class<T> type)` tells the JDBC driver that you want the data in the column converted to that specific class *and* the compiler that you'll be getting that type back from the method, so you don't need a cast.